# Need help with PermissionsBukkit

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I'm having a hard time getting PermissionsBukkit to work. [This is the server log](http://pastebin.com/cERUMW8G), and [this is the config file for PermissionsBukkit](http://pastebin.com/V5iCG3xY). Why can't I get this to work?

'MYUSER` should be admin and allowed to build/remove blocks?

If I dump MYUSER I get this:

```
> permissions dump MYUSER
13:37:29 [INFO] [==== Page 1 of 3 ====]
13:37:29 [INFO] Node lwc.admin=true (PermissionsBukkit)
.... MOAR ....
```

As you all see MYUSER has the `lwc.admin=true`, and it's enabled in the admin group.

Comment: Your permissions.yml file is not where server is looking it for.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using something other then PermissionsBukkit for now. The Bukkit team is swamped with other stuff, and because of that have switched there focus away from the Permissions system. PermissionEx is a great alternative

Comment: The Bukkit team is swamped *now*, since 1.0 just came out, but when this question was asked, I don't think that was the problem.